# How do I eliminate this circular dependency

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter, circular-dependency

The circular dependency between self.buttons and self.radiobuttons has been impossible for me to solve

```
class Program(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, title, size):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(f"{size[0]}x{size[1]}")
        
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self, background = "#D3D3D3")
        self.frame.pack(expand = 1, fill = tk.BOTH)

        self.entries = Entries(self) 
        self.output = Output(self)
        self.buttons = Buttons(self, self.entries, self.output, self.radiobuttons) # here
        self.radiobuttons = (self, self.buttons) # here


        self.filemenu = FileMenu(self)


        self.mainloop()
```

I am trying to use functools among other things to fix my problem but I can't seem to fix it. I could always just move the entirety of one class into the other but it would make using classes redundant

Comment: You can use another instance function of class `Buttons` to pass `self.radiobuttons` to it after `self.radiobuttons` is created.

Comment: Note that it is not recommended (also not good design) to call `mainloop()` inside `__init__()`.

Comment: @acw1668 - This is my first program with classes and I sort of get what you're saying, but I'm not fully sure how to implement it. Can you write a scaffold for me please? Also thanks for the design tip, I've seen people using if __name__ == __main__ and I didn't think much of it. Now that I know I'll make sure to implement it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another class method of `Buttons` to pass `self.radiobuttons` to it after `self.radiobuttons` is created.

Below is an example:

```py
class Buttons(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, entries, output):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.entries = entries
        self.output = output

    # another class method to pass radiobuttons
    def set_radiobuttons(self, radiobuttons):
        self.radiobuttons = radiobuttons
        # do whatever you want on radiobuttons

class Radiobuttons(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, buttons):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.buttons = buttons

class Program(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, title, size):
        super().__init__()
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(f"{size[0]}x{size[1]}")

        self.frame = tk.Frame(self, background = "#D3D3D3")
        self.frame.pack(expand = 1, fill = tk.BOTH)

        self.entries = Entries(self)
        self.output = Output(self)
        self.buttons = Buttons(self, self.entries, self.output)
        self.radiobuttons = Radiobuttons(self, self.buttons)
        self.buttons.set_radiobuttons(self.radiobuttons) # pass self.radiobuttons to class Buttons

        self.filemenu = FileMenu(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Program("Hello World", (600,400))
    app.mainloop() # call mainloop() here instead of inside __init__()
```

Comment: It shows this error <AttributeError: 'Buttons' object has no attribute 'radiobuttons'>

Comment: I don't have the error in my example code.

Comment: Buttons requires radiobuttons in it's arguments despite the fact that you are giving it the argument just later down in the Program() class. Any ideas on how to fix this? The error: TypeError: Buttons.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'radiobuttons'

Comment: Note that I have removed `radiobuttons` argument from `Buttons.__init__()` definition.

Comment: https://github.com/tomasvana10/calculator_sdd 
This is a link to my program as is, if you are still interested in helping

Comment: Typo: `self.radionbuttons` should be `self.radiobuttons`.

Comment: Thank you, it works fine. I’m embarrassed for missing that lol